# When is is appropriate to have multiple java statements on one line?

Tags: java

I've seen code that looks like this:

```
String name;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name"); name = scan.nextLine();
```

**As opposed to:**

```
String name;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name");
name = scan.nextLine();
```

Which one is generally regarded as better practice?

Comment: I say after every semicolon.  There should be a newline

Comment: Whichever is easiest for you to read. Although, its common practice to start new statments on a new line

Comment: Well the first thing I'd do is move the declaration to the point of first use... which makes it more readable *and* only being 3 lines long, without having to have two statements on a single line.

Answer (score 5):

The usual convention is to put each statement on its own line. According to [Google's style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.3-one-statement-per-line):

> 4.3 One statement per line
>
> Each statement is followed by a line-break.

The second snippet in your question complies with this rule. Following conventions makes it easier for people to read each others' code.

Note you can use an IDE to format your code (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse) and it will move this around for you.

Regardless of standards, following the style used in existing code is usually a good idea. Especially, reformatting in the same check-in as code changes makes it hard to see what changed when bringing in new versions.

In a team situation, formatting is not the place to express your individuality. Use the same formatting as the other people on the team. Reformatting wars between team members who have their IDEs set with different formatting rules are really annoying.

Also, not declaring variables until they're used is the preferred style. Declaring a local variable without assigning a value means it can't be used until something assigns it a value anyway.

Comment: ctrl alt L in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to make your code as readable as possible. And generally, your code is more readable the better formatted it is. Placing two statements on the same line is usually seen as harder to read then having each statement get it's own line.

Answer (score 1):

Either of course, are allowable.  This comes down to personal preference and what you see as more readable.  Seeing that a program is written out line by line, and there's logic in each line, I'd opt for the second one.  It makes it a little easier to understand what's going on, and easier to debug in my eyes.  Performance wise, there's absolutely no difference between the two.  To more directly answer your question, in my eyes, it's never appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The rule (yahoo) when modifying; code exactly like (in the style of) the programmer who wrote the original code.  When writing new code code exactly like the other programmers on the team.  If it's just you then whatever you think is the most readable.  Keep in mind some source indentation tools will separate multi statement lines.

Your example seams to make a little more sense to me if coded in-line.

```
String name = scan.nextLine();
```